# What do the characters that accompany Willard in Apocalypse Now represent in relation to the morality and insanity?

Tags: character, film-techniques, apocalypse-now

What do the characters on the boat (Lance, Clean, Chief and Chef) represent in Apocalypse Now and how do they relate to the metaphor involving insanity? Any answers good, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A [study guide](http://www.gradesaver.com/apocalypse-now/study-guide/summary-chapter-13-mr-cleans-death-chapter-15-kurtzs-compound) for Apocalypse Now offers this summary:*

> ...these characters fit into common war film tropes:
>
> - Mr. Clean is the young upstart who requires protection from his stronger comrades
> - Chief is the hardened soldier with a heart of gold who plays by the rules
> - Chef is the sensitive soul always on the verge of a breakdown
> - Lance exists in his own world